# SQL Server color coding for objects in text editor not working

Tags: sql-server

SQL server suddenly stopped color coding my objects (tables, schemas, ect) green like they are supposed to be. It still colors keywords blue, and comments dark green, and strings red, like it should. I've tried "refresh local cache" for IntelliSense. I've tried restarting SSMS. I've gone to options where you can change the color coding and fonts for the text editor and "set default". It isn't the end of the world, but I liked that feature and have no idea why it stopped.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of what you are trying to explain

Comment: tables and schemas default color in SSMS is black unless it is a system table or catalog view which are green by default.

Comment: But this is not a programming question, please ask it somewhere else...

Comment: @SeanLange You are right. System tables are in green. I'm using MSsql 2016 and the tutorial I'm watching to learn SQL server must be a different version, where ALL his objects are color coded green. Thanks for helping out a fellow Sean.

Comment: The presenter must have adjusted the colors. Happy coding